# Cordova splash screen plugin iPad landscape mode issue

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen, landscape

I am using the Cordova splash screen plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) in my hybrid mobile app targeted for iOS. I have all the splash screen images added to my project as below:

[image]

The reason for using this plugin is to elongate the time for which the splash screen is shown and I manually hide it later in the app. So my config.xml has the following declarations:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
```

This plugin works fine in the portrait mode on iPhone and iPad. But on the iPad in landscape mode, the plugin shows the splash image in portrait mode and consequently my first app view also shows in the portrait mode even though the device is in landscape mode. Below screenshot shows the splash screen and the black blank portion below it when the iPad is in landscape mode.

[image]

Any advise on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please double check the width and height for your landscape pngs in your config.xml?

Comment: I have the following images in my project for iPad splash screens: Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (2048x1536px), Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024x768px), Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (1536x2048px), Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768x1024px)

Comment: I have opened a JIRA ticket with Apache Cordova: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this commit, fixes these weird handlings on a iPad for me: https://github.com/EducationPerfect/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/commit/49bee9f86623361ef84415025ea08ea38835f387